# Unix command history -- finding a command fast

Tags: bash, unix

Is there a way (or a specific shell) to navigate the history in the following way: let's say I wrote the following command two weeks ago:

```
scp ../../../file.txt ../../../...
```

I don't want to use the arrows to find the command because it will take too much time. Instead, I'd like to type `scp` to narrow down the possibilities and then browse the history.

Comment: Note that this is a function of your shell (bash, tcsh, zsh, fish ...) not of "unix" in some general sense. If you don't have a clue what I'm talking the bash related answer below will probably work for you. Or try `printenv SHELL`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `Ctrl-r` (reverse search) each time you hit `Ctrl-r` you go backward to the next earliest match in history so this is likely the best option.

However, there are other options as well like the `!` operator. If the last command was unique (`scp` was not executed again since then) you can use `!scp` which will execute the last command that began with `scp` in your history. Also, if you do the `history | grep scp` approach you can use `!` to execute the command number. For instance:

```
$ history | egrep scp
 268  scp foo@bar:/home/foo/file .
$ !268
```

That `!268` will execute command 268 exactly as it appears in the `history` output sans the preceding number.

Comment: Also, `!scp` will give you the most recent history entry beginning with "scp"

Answer (score 3):

Try `Ctrl+r`, it should do what you need.

Answer (score 3):

I use

```
history | grep scp
```

and then copy, paste and edit (if required) or just `! <command number>`

Comment: Thanks. This is indeed simple, I should have thought about it... I'll use the Ctrl+r option, it's faster.

Answer (score 3):

Try `Ctrl+r` to search the history. You should get a prompt like the following:

```
(reverse-i-search)`':
```

Answer (score 2):

I have

```
"\e[B": history-search-forward
"\e[A": history-search-backward
```

in $HOME/.inputrc, and I believe this ties the behaviour you want to the up and arrow keys.
To elaborate, 'man readline' tells us history-search-{forward,backward} will take into account the current string typed on the command line:

```
   history-search-forward
          Search  forward  through  the history for the string of characters between the start of the current line
          and the current cursor position (the point).  This is a non-incremental search.
   history-search-backward
          Search backward through the history for the string of characters between the start of the  current  line
          and the point.  This is a non-incremental search.
```

Comment: I've bount it to the Pg-Up and Pg-Down keys.

Answer (score 0):

Use `vi` navigation:

```
set -o vi
[Esc]/scp[Enter]
```

Hit `n` to go to the next match, or `N` to the previous match. `i` to insert text, `A` to append